# How to get Intellisense in LESS files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: css, visual-studio, less, frontend

I recently moved my CSS structure to LESS and it's great, I really see many benefits from using LESS compared to plain CSS.

The only issue I had so far is with Visual Studio 2015, because my LESS code is distributed into different files and folders I always get a Intellisense error like "**Undeclared mixin**" or "**Undeclared variable**".

[image: Intellisense Error]

This simply happens because my mixins, variables and other pieces of code are in different files and there's no automatic way for VS to know where they are.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, have you installed the [**Web Essentials LESS**](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less) extension?

On second thoughts , just fit a reference comment on top of your document like so:

`/// <reference path="variables.less" />`

Where the `path=""` will be the exact path to your file.

Comment: ahh!! this is great thanks!! I do have Web Essentials LESS extension :) but it was not picking up those references. But your answer works just perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add "@import (reference) ..." into the file that use variables.

```
@import (reference) "FileWithVariables.less";
```